# "Inheritance" in C's structs?

Tags: c, gcc, struct

Here I'm a bit confused about this code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct test_struct {
    uint8_t f;
    uint8_t weird[];
};

int main(void) {
    struct {
        struct test_struct tst;
        uint8_t weird[256];
    } test_in = {};

    printf("%u\n", test_in.weird[0]); // 0

    test_in.tst.weird[0] = 1;

    printf("%u\n", test_in.weird[0]); // 1

    return 0;
}
```

I didn't know that it is possible to use struct's fields this way, so I have two questions:

- How is it called in C?
- And, of course, how does it work? (Why `weird` field was changed when I don't change it directly, I thought these are two different fields?)

Comment: What's strange about it? It works like any other field.

Comment: `test_in = {};` is invalid C.

Comment: @Lundin It compiles for me in GCC (granted, I get a warning with `-Wpedantic -std=C17`).

Comment: It's a question about VLAs

Comment: @Fe2O3, what does it stand for?

Comment: @Fe2O3 No it is a question about flexible array members. Similar, but not quite the same term.

Comment: @Dai gcc used as conforming C compiler: `error: invalid use of structure with flexible array member [-Wpedantic]` ... `error: ISO C forbids empty initializer braces [-Wpedantic]`

Comment: Besides. It's not inheritence. It's composition.

Comment: 'V'ariable 'L'ength 'A'rray... Try using some printing of `sizeof` and you'll see that `test_in.tst` is the size of 1 uint8_t. You think it's a full blown struct, but...

Comment: @Lundin FAM v. VLA... Sorry... Much of a muchness to those of us with old compilers...

Comment: @klutt It's gnu17 language, not C. Far as I know C would require the flexible array member to be at the end of the struct(s), nested or not. gcc in C mode seems to agree.

Comment: @Lundin Didn't see the FAM first. It looked like the question was about a struct in a struct.

Comment: Anyway, @Dai would need to clarify if they are interested to know how this works in standard C or how it works in the GNU extension, since those would be different languages. I added the gcc tag to the question.

Comment: And regarding that same old boring "it compiles but I get warnings" discussion, please see [What must a C compiler do when it finds an error?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/277340)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Here I'm a bit confused about this code:

The short answer is: the code has **undefined behavior**.

> How is it called in C? How does it work?

- `struct test_struct` is defined with its last member as an array of unspecified length: `uint8_t weird[];` This member is called a *flexible array member*, not to be confused with a variable length array.

> **6.7.2 Type specifiers**
>
> [...]
>
> 20     As a special case, the last member of a structure with more than one named member may have an incomplete array type; this is called a  *flexible array member*. In most situations, the flexible array member is ignored. In particular, the size of the structure is as if the flexible array member were omitted except that it may have more trailing padding than the omission would imply. However, when a `.` (or `->`) operator has a left operand that is (a pointer to) a structure with a flexible array member and the right operand names that member, it behaves as if that member were replaced with the longest array (with the same element type) that would not make the structure larger than the object being accessed; the offset of the array shall remain that of the flexible array member, even if this would differ from that of the replacement array. If this array would have no elements, it behaves as if it had one element but the behavior is undefined if any attempt is made to access that element or to generate a pointer one past it.

- if you allocate such a structure from the heap with extra space for array elements, these elements can be accessed via the `weird` member up to the number of elements thus allocated.
- The C Standard mandates that such a structure can only be defined as a member of another structure or union if it appears as the last member of said aggregate. In the posted code, the programmer violates this constraint, so accessing elements of `test_in.tst.weird` has undefined behavior, and so does accessing elements of `test_in.weird`.
- The programmer also assumes that the `test_in.tst.weird` array and the `test_in.weird` array overlap exactly, which may be the case but is not guaranteed, nor supported: code relying on this type of aliasing has undefined behavior as well.
- In your example, assuming the compiler accepts the empty initializer `{}` (part of the next C Standard and borrowed from C++), it seems to work as expected, but this is not guaranteed and alignment issues may cause it to fail as shown in the modified version below:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct test_struct {
    uint8_t f;
    uint8_t weird[];
};

struct test_struct1 {
    int x;
    uint8_t f;
    uint8_t weird[];
};

int main(void) {
    struct {
        struct test_struct tst;
        uint8_t weird[256];
    } test_in = {};

    struct {
        struct test_struct1 tst;
        uint8_t weird[256];
    } test_in1 = {};

    printf("modifying test_in.weird[0]:\n");
    printf("%u\n", test_in.weird[0]); // 0
    test_in.tst.weird[0] = 1;
    printf("%u\n", test_in.weird[0]); // 1

    printf("modifying test_in1.weird[0]:\n");
    printf("%u\n", test_in1.weird[0]); // 0
    test_in1.tst.weird[0] = 1;
    printf("%u\n", test_in1.weird[0]); // 0?

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
chqrlie$ make 220930-flexible.run
clang -O3 -std=c11 -Weverything -o 220930-flexible 220930-flexible.c
220930-flexible.c:17:28: warning: field 'tst' with variable sized type 'struct test_struct' not at
      the end of a struct or class is a GNU extension [-Wgnu-variable-sized-type-not-at-end]
        struct test_struct tst;
                           ^
220930-flexible.c:19:17: warning: use of GNU empty initializer extension [-Wgnu-empty-initializer]
    } test_in = {};
                ^
220930-flexible.c:22:29: warning: field 'tst' with variable sized type 'struct test_struct1' not
      at the end of a struct or class is a GNU extension [-Wgnu-variable-sized-type-not-at-end]
        struct test_struct1 tst;
                            ^
220930-flexible.c:24:18: warning: use of GNU empty initializer extension [-Wgnu-empty-initializer]
    } test_in1 = {};
                 ^
4 warnings generated.
modifying test_in.weird[0]:
0
1
modifying test_in1.weird[0]:
0
0
```

Comment: What's the section of C standard describe it?

Comment: @k1r1t0: I amended the answer with a quote from the standard. The language is somewhat obscure... I hope my explanation is correct and easier to grasp.

Comment: @k1r1t0 Array or Struct declaration, i've provided you with the links to it. At the end of those pages, you'll find the references to the actual C Standard.

Answer (score 1):

On the contrary as described in the comments section above, a declaration like

```
int array[];
```

is not a Variable Length Array, it's either called [Arrays of unknown size](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array#Arrays_of_unknown_size) (cppreference) or [Arrays of Length Zero](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-12.2.0/gcc/Zero-Length.html#Zero-Length) (gcc).

An example of a VLA would be:

```
void foo(size_t n)
{
    int array[n]; //n is not available at compile time
}
```

Based on the comment below (from the cppreference - see provided link):

> Within a struct definition, an array of unknown size may appear as the last member (as long as there is at least one other named member), in which case it is a special case known as flexible array member. See [struct](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct#Explanation) (section Explanation) for details:

```
struct s { int n; double d[]; }; // s.d is a flexible array member 
struct s *s1 = malloc(sizeof (struct s) + (sizeof (double) * 8)); // as if d was double d[8]
```

Comment: I still can't understand why was the `weird` field changed in both structs, when I change it only in `test_in.tst`?

Comment: Does my addition to the answer explain it?

Comment: The difference is that your example is conforming standard C, whereas the OP's code isn't... Again, it isn't clear if the question is about the behavior of GNU extensions or the behavior of the C language.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct test_struct {
    uint8_t f;
    uint8_t weird[];
};

int main(void) {
    struct {
        struct test_struct tst;
        uint8_t weird[256];
    } test_in = {};
```

Effectively, before there were FAM's in the language, what you've declared is:

```
int main(void) {
    struct {
        struct { uint8_t f; } tst;
        union {
            uint8_t weird0[1]; // any non-zero size up to 256
            uint8_t weird1[256];
        } overlay;
    } test_in = {};
```

Comment: What does FAM stand for?

Comment: Except before flexible array members, then adding some `[1]` array at the end, aka "the struct hack", wasn't well-defined beyond the first item, and could mean writing into padding bytes or cause an out of bounds access crash, as it pleased. I'm not sure what language you are speaking of though, in case of the gnu90 language it supported zero-length arrays as the ancestor of flexible array members. In case of the C language then there are just multiple errors and non-conformance.

Comment: @k1r1t0 Lundin answered that about 15 min ago in a comment. 'F'lexible 'A'rray 'M'embers....

Comment: Because we really needed to invent more TLA...

Comment: @Lundin Just to say, some of us wrote C code when function prototypes weren't really important to the compiler (and, somehow, we got code to work...) Times change... Some of us have a hard time letting go of _the old ways_...

Comment: Your example with an `overlay` union is confusing.

Comment: @chqrlie One man's meat is another.... It's all just bytes in memory somewhere being addressed... The "union" is a hacky presentation, I agree, but it is an alternative way to see that the OP's 1st struct defines only a single member, and the next lot of bytes can be accessed by two different names... Crude, but perhaps helpful to the OP... Perhaps... We can only try...

Comment: @Fe2O3 Function prototypes were _always_ important to the compiler. The difference is: C99 compiler spotting that I'm about to get run over by a car: "look out, a car!" Me: "Oh crap!" - jumps out of the way. C90 compiler spotting that I'm about to get run over by a car:  Maybe it isn't a car but an integer? Closes eyes and covers ears, staying silent. Me: *splat*

Comment: @Fe2O3 I was trying to make a joke. But well, no fun allowed on SO...

Comment: @Lundin Missed that... Sorry... Too used to being lambasted by others... My apologies for misinterpreting your good intentions. "social media", eh? (Taking down my harsh _old timer_ reply... Too many wet-behind-the-ears whippersnappers who don't appreciate what the world was like before 16Gb of RAM was around...) Cheers! `:-)`

Comment: @Fe2O3: coding on BSD on a PDP 11/34 in 1978... It must have been Bill Joy's 1BSD add-on on top of unix v6 :) What a blessing to have been there. I was still toying with assembly on punch cards back then, and loving it.

Comment: @Lundin OT: "TLA" is a misnomer. Should be "TLI" "Three Letter Initialism"... An _acronym_, like a _synonym_ or _antonym_ is a "word". "NASA" is an acronym because it is spoken as if it was a word. "UN" is an initialism, because each letter is enunciated separately... So, most "TLA"s are actually "TLI"s... Fun fact! `:-)` "TLA" is, itself, a "TLI"...

Comment: @chqrlie "Blessing?" Run up 'vi' on one terminal and listen to the whole office groan and complain about their terminals going dead... Ah... Those were the days, to be sure... I had hair!!! `:-)`

Comment: @Fe2O3 TLA _obviously_ stands for Three Letter Abbreviation. Just like FAM _obviously_ stands for [Foreign Affairs Manual](https://fam.state.gov/).

Answer (score 1):

The provided code is just invalid.

You declared a structure with a *flexible array member*

```
struct test_struct {
    uint8_t f;
    uint8_t weird[];
};
```

From the C Standard (6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers)

> 18 As a special case, the last element of a structure with more than
> one named member may have an incomplete array type; this is called a
> *flexible array member*.

As it is seen from the quote such a member must be the last element of a structure. So the above structure declaration is correct.

However then in main you declared another unnamed structure

```
int main(void) {
    struct {
        struct test_struct tst;
        uint8_t weird[256];
    } test_in = {};
    //...
```

that contains as member an element of the structure with the flexible array element that now is not the last element of the unnamed structure. So such a declaration is invalid.

Secondly, you are using empty braces to initialize an object of the unnamed structure. Opposite to C++ in C you may not use empty braces to initialize objects.